# How do I output the class name in PlayFramework 2 Logging?

Tags: logging, playframework-2.0, logback

I setup a logging.xml file as shown below. This file includes output to the console as well as a rolling file which gets a new file for everyday:

```
<configuration>
<appender name="FILE" class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.RollingFileAppender">
    <file>${application.home}/logs/application.log</file>
    <rollingPolicy class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.TimeBasedRollingPolicy">
        <FileNamePattern>${application.home}/logs/application.%d{yyyy-MM-dd}.log</FileNamePattern>
    </rollingPolicy>

    <layout class="ch.qos.logback.classic.PatternLayout">
        <Pattern>%-4relative [%thread] %-5level %logger{35} - %msg%n</Pattern>
    </layout>
</appender>
<appender name="A1" class="ch.qos.logback.core.ConsoleAppender">
    <encoder>
        <pattern>%p %d{ISO8601} %c - %m%n</pattern>
    </encoder>
</appender>
<logger name="javax.faces" level="debug" />
<root level="info">
    <appender-ref ref="A1" />
    <appender-ref ref="FILE" />
</root>
</configuration>
```

My question with this is how do I output the class name as well? I tried reading the Play documentation and could not find the answer to that... It's very hard in a production environment to not see classnames as well. Thanks for the help!

Comment: Could you show what it currently outputs?

Comment: As mentioned in the docs, doing this on a production environment might not be a good idea
**Generating the caller class information is not particularly fast. Thus, its use should be avoided unless execution speed is not an issue.**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the [doc](http://logback.qos.ch/manual/layouts.html#conversionWord), to get the class name, you should use in your pattern `%class{0}`

Comment: @KVISH Could you tell how you made it work? I am getting this `play.Logger$ALogger - 2016-10-02 01:19:47,684 - My application log`. Play version 2.2. It prints ALogger class name, and using `private static final Logger.ALogger logger = Logger.of(MyClass.class);` doesn't even prints the log. I dont want to add each class name in logger.xml, like "<logger name="application" level="INFO"/>"

Comment: This question was a long time ago and I no longer have access to the code for this. Also, the version was 1.x of play, not sure if its relevant.

Comment: @KVISH Thank you for giving your time. FInally found this : http://stackoverflow.com/a/28820410/1874627 . This cannot be done by play, one has to use play.Logger.underlying() to get slf4j logger. Tested and worked.

Answer (score 1):

The playframework uses slf4j as logging engine and does not print the class name even after the following expression :

> ```
> <appender name="STDOUT" class="ch.qos.logback.core.ConsoleAppender">
>     <encoder>
>         <pattern>%d{ISO8601} %-5level [%thread] %logger{36}: %class{0}::%method:%line - %msg%n</pattern>
>     </encoder>
> </appender>
> ```

The fix however is to use :

> Logger.underlying().info("My logging message");

to get the classname and method and line number.
Output :

> 2015-12-22 17:43:49,969 INFO  [play-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-30]
>   application: MyController::get:82 - My logging message

Answer (score -2):

seems problem in your private implementation of PatternLayout class in ch.qos.logback.classic.
PatternLayout. Try to use standard log4j implementation. And how are you getting logger instance, as like this: private static Logger logger =
Logger.getLogger
(MyClass.class); ?

Comment: Nope...that `getLogger` function doesn't exist in `play.Logger`. So i'm just doing `Logger.info`, `Logger.error`, etc.

Comment: One more thing...I'm using in Play! (as mentioned above)...I'd rather not bring in another Logging framework as the framework includes on already...was wondering if there was a way to do it in the current framework.

Answer (score -3):

Please read the [docs](http://www.playframework.org/documentation/2.0/SettingsLogger) carefully. Also play2 uses logback as logging engine, so read more about it on Logback's [official web site.](http://logback.qos.ch/)

Comment: You are not answering the question.