# start shell script from "play dist" fails to locate logger.xml in JAR file

Tags: playframework, playframework-2.0, playframework-2.1

I'm new to Play 2.1 and am trying to figure out the easiest way to deploy Play into our ops environment.  The out-of-the-box Play 2.1 capability that holds the most promise is

```
play dist
```

Which builds a ZIP file that contains all the supporting JARs to run my app as well as some start shell script which launches the whole thing.  Works like a champ.

The problem is that my application requires more fine-grained logging than afforded by the out-of-the-box one-size-fits-all logs/application.log.  On my dev box, I figured out how to create and configure conf/logger.xml to perform old-school topic logging per Controller class (any class, actually, but lets stick with the Controllers for now).  This works fine on my dev box when I run though the play console, but when I build my application through "play dist" and start it on the app server with just the start shell script,  I never get the logfiles that this logger is configured to produce.  I also believe, but without those logs I don't know, that the start command also fails to locate the Global object I have configured for my project.

Looking into the JAR file that is my application I can see the conf/application.conf and conf/logger.xml files are in the JAR, they just aren't being loaded as the application fires up.

How do I get the execution of the start script to load the logger.xml from the JAR file?  Do I really have to specify it on the commandline with -D or should it just load directly out of the application's JAR?

Answer (score 2):

I recommend editing your production start script to add the following to your java command line:

```
-Dconfig.resource=/conf/logger.xml
```

That will find the logger config if it's in your classpath. (I think there's also a `-Dconfig.file` alternative). I also recommend adding a configuration directory to your classpath, so your play start command will be something like:

```
MYAPP_HOME=~/myapp
java -cp $MYAPP_HOME:$MYAPP_HOME/lib/* play.core.server.NettyServer $MYAPP_HOME
```

By getting your config from a directory in your classpath rather than from a jar file, you gain the ability to edit it, or to specify different versions.

Comment: I have arrived at a similar conclusion.  The ZIP file + the start script produced by "play dist" MUST be modified on the production machines with -D's to get the thing working.  This feels like a bug in "play dist" to me, but it can be worked around.

Comment: There appears, in Play 2.1.1, to be no way to get it to classpath load the logger.xml from the application's JARed.  The -Dlogger.resource=logger.xml failed to locate the file.  I only got success by copying the logger.xml into the distribution directory and -Dlogger.file=conf/logger.xml on the start.  Sigh.

Comment: Interesting! I'm still on Play 2.0.4. You might investigate if logger.xml is in your classpath by trying `.getClass().getResource("/conf/logger.xml"`). I find that I need to write my own start script anyway, for other reasons.