# Playframework quit logging after application starts, but works for Global.onStart()

Tags: java, logging, playframework, slf4j

I wrote a play 2.2.1 application and I have problems with logging. I defined a logger per class in this way:

```
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;
import org.slf4j.Logger;

public class Foo extends Controller {
     private static Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(Foo.class);

     public Result bar(){
        logger.info("Bar called");
        .
        .
        .

     }

}
```

I am not using a `logger.xml`. Everything perfectly works in `dev` mode and every class logs fine. When I run in `dist` mode, it stops logging after the application is started. Any idea about what I am doing wrong or what else could I check?
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to have the logger running adding a `logger.xml` file and explicitly calling it with the `-Dlogger.file` option. I am a bit confused by the fact that all that should be logged bacause of the Global.onStart() method was correctly logged, while, after the application was started, there was no more logs (but only on `dist` mode, with the `run` mode logs where fine).

Maybe my issue is related with [this other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16906837).

Answer (score 0):

I would check log level, probably try setting it explicitly (in conf):
logger=DEBUG

Comment: Already tried. It anyway stops after the application is started.