# play framework 2.2.x logger not working properly after Global.onStart()

Tags: java, playframework

Logger works fine under the debug run mode and run mode. After I build the application as a standalone (By using `play dist`), the logger won't log while the application is running.

Same issue here : [Playframework quit logging after application starts, but works for Global.onStart()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25995651/playframework-quit-logging-after-application-starts-but-works-for-global-onstar)

but after I explicitly call logger.xml the problem is not solved.