# In Grails 3.1.x, how do I configure grails logging to include the class name in the logging statement?

Tags: grails, logback, grails-3.1, apache-commons-logging

The class that gets printed is the logger's class, not the class that contains the log statement.

logback pattern:

```
pattern = "%date{ISO8601} [%level] %class{100} %msg%n"
```

Calling logger in MyController.class:

```
log.info("Some message);
```

results in

```
2017-03-21 19:06:50,824 [INFO] org.apache.commons.logging.Log$Log$info$0 Some message
```

There is a very similar problem in the Play framework, but the solution is Play specific:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/28820410/258896

I tried to explicitly get the logger, but it made no difference in the output.

```
static Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(MyController.class)
```

Using:

Grails 3.1.14

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
pattern = "%date{ISO8601} [%level] %logger{0} %msg%n"
```

Explanation of value in brackets [here](https://logback.qos.ch/manual/layouts.html#conversionWord).