# In Grails 3.1.x, how do I configure grails logging to include the class, method and line number in the logging statement?

Tags: grails, logback, grails-3.1, apache-commons-logging

The class that gets printed is the logging framework's class, not the groovy class that contains the log statement. The method is always 'call', and line number is always -1.

logback pattern:

```
pattern = "%date{ISO8601} [%-5level] %class{100}::%method:%line %msg%n"
```

Calling logger in MyController.class:

```
log.info("Some message);
```

results in

```
2017-03-22 09:44:28,088 [INFO ] org.apache.commons.logging.Log$info$0::call:-1 Some message
```

Alternately, trying to use the logger conversion word in the pattern can provide the class, but not the method or line number.

logback pattern:

```
pattern = "%date{ISO8601} [%-5level] %logger{100}::%method:%line %msg%n"
```

Calling logger in MyController.class:

```
log.info("Some message);
```

results in

```
2017-03-22 09:48:13,185 [INFO ] grails.app.controllers.com.mypackage.MyController::call:-1 Some message
```

There is a very similar problem in the Play framework, but the solution is Play specific:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/28820410/258896

Using:

Grails 3.1.14