# PlayFramework Logback printing caller class name

Tags: playframework-2.0, logback

I am using Play 2.1 (Java) and the default logback (1.0.7) logger that comes with Play. In one of my controller I'm using "play.Logger" to print a debug log message. Despite mentioning "`%class`" in the logger.xml, the caller class name is not getting printed. Rather "`play.Logger$ALogger`" is getting printed. I debugged till logback's `ch.qos.logback.classic.spi.CallerData` where it returns the stacktrace as an array to identify the caller class. In the array, my caller controller class is at the bottom of the array while at the top is the "`play.Logger.ALogger`" item and that's what is used in "`ch.qos.logback.classic.pattern.ClassOfCallerConverter`" to print the class `name(cda[0].getClassName())`.

I did look at other similar threads [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11094048/how-do-i-output-the-class-name-in-playframework-2-logging) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15258144/how-do-i-configure-logback-to-print-out-the-class-name) but they don't seem to fix this.

Here's my XML

```
<appender name="FILE_DEBUG" class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.RollingFileAppender">
    <file>${application.home}/logs/debug_log.log</file>
    <layout class="ch.qos.logback.classic.PatternLayout">
        <pattern>%date - [%level] - from %logger %class in %thread %n%message%n%xException%n</pattern>
    </layout>
    <filter class="ch.qos.logback.classic.filter.ThresholdFilter">
        <level>DEBUG</level>
    </filter>
    <rollingPolicy class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.TimeBasedRollingPolicy">
        <fileNamePattern>${application.home}/logs/debug_log.%d{yyyy-MM-dd}.log</fileNamePattern>
        <maxHistory>30</maxHistory>
    </rollingPolicy>
</appender>
```

Am I missing something?

Answer (score 0):

I've been investigating same issue lately and here is my solution: you need to set `includeCallerData` flag by adding

```
    <includeCallerData>true</includeCallerData>
```

to your appender configuration.

Btw, if you are using `ch.qos.logback.classic.AsyncAppender`, you must enable the flag there as well, but once you do that, you don't have to set it anywhere else as `AsyncAppender` modifies logging events by injecting caller data into it.

In my case it was sufficient to add a NOP appender to the root logger configuration to make caller data available everywhere

```
    <appender name="NOP" class="ch.qos.logback.core.helpers.NOPAppender" />
    <appender name="ASYNC.NOP" class="ch.qos.logback.classic.AsyncAppender">
      <includeCallerData>true</includeCallerData>
      <appender-ref ref="NOP" />
    </appender>

    <root level="...">
        ...
        <appender-ref ref="ASYNC.NOP" />
    </root>
```

Keep in mind that acquiring caller data may have severe impact on performance, so I would not use it in production.